# How do I get customer list into a winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get a customer list from `Customers.cs` into `MainForm.cs`. Is there a way to get the list from `Customers.cs` without using a sql server? I want it to show the first name under the column name `colFirstName` and the last name under the column name `colLastName` on the `MainForm.cs`. I have a code that I used for `MainForm.cs` to get the `sql` customer list, but I am required to get the customer list without using a `sql` connection.

`Customers.cs` code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassProject2.Data
{
public class Customers
{
    public Customers()
    {
        _customers = new List<Customer>() //Customer list
        {
            new Customer(_ids.Next())
            {
                FirstName = "Bob",
                LastName = "Miller"
            },
            new Customer(_ids.Next())
            {
                FirstName = "Sue",
                LastName = "Storm"
            },
            new Customer(_ids.Next())
            {
                FirstName = "Peter",
                LastName = "Parker"
            }
        };
    }

    public Customer Add ( Customer customer )
    {
        if (customer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customer));

        Validator.ValidateObject(customer, new ValidationContext(customer));

        if (_customers.Any(c => String.Compare(c.FirstName, customer.FirstName, true) == 0 &&
                                String.Compare(c.LastName, customer.LastName, true) == 0))
            throw new ArgumentException("Customer already exists.", nameof(customer));

        customer.Id = _ids.Next();

        _customers.Add(customer);

        return customer;
    }

    public Customer Get ( int id )
    {
        return (from c in _customers
                where id == c.Id
                select c
               ).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll ()
    {
        return _customers;
    }

    public void Remove(int id)
    {
        //Verify > 0
        if (id <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Id must be > 0", nameof(id));

        //Find the item
        var item = _customers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);

        //Remove it
        if (item != null)
            _customers.Remove(item);
    }

    private readonly List<Customer> _customers;
    private readonly Sequence _ids = new Sequence(100);
}
}
```

Code that I used for `MainForm.cs`

```
private void IsLinkClicked(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
            DataGridView.HitTestInfo Hti = gridCustomers.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (Hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            {
                if (gridCustomers.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gridCustomers.CurrentCell = gridCustomers[Hti.ColumnIndex, Hti.RowIndex];
                }
            }
            if(Hti.ColumnIndex < 0 || Hti.ColumnIndex > gridCustomers.ColumnCount)
            {
                value = false;
            }
            CustomerForm cf = new CustomerForm();
            cf.editMode = true;                
            int rowIndex = gridCustomers.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            cf.id = gridCustomers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["colId"].Value.ToString();
            cf.FName = gridCustomers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["colFirstName"].Value.ToString();
            cf.LName = gridCustomers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["colLastName"].Value.ToString();
            cf.Show();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to Get The list without having a connection to the database you're trying to pull data out of.

you can do it with dataAdapter and a Dataset to be in Unconnected Mode 
In your dataset you can only put SELECT statement if you don't want to modify the database and Just Show Data to the User

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Mark it as soon as it awnsered